# folder size not corresponding to files inside

Tags: linux, centos, disk-space-utilization, whm

I have a problem! My server (Centos OS WHM) is out of space. Browse directories and naturally the biggest directory is /home/userfolder/.

Using the `du -sch *` command, I can check the size **99GB**.

```
[home]# du -sch *
99G     userfolder
36K     latest
100G    total
```

But when I enter the directory and use the same command, I see that the total size of the found files and directory is **55GB**.

```
[userfolder]# du -sch *
55G     total
```

As the server backup was weighing approximately **45GB**, I thought it was the problem so I deleted it. But it wasn't even in that directory so it really couldn't be the problem. Could anyone give me a hint of what it could be or if I did something wrong?

Comment: This is dupicate question from SU https://superuser.com/questions/602818/how-to-get-the-actual-directory-size-out-of-du. Check the solutions there.

Comment: You are missing the hidden files with your second command.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider – 
Can you tell me what the correct command would be?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10768/find-biggest-files-or-directories/10769#10769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it cpanel? Check your trash. It's probably your recycle bin that has a lot of files.

Comment: Dude, it works! THANK YOU SO MUCH!